# GNU Octave Command Window unreadable text

Tags: octave

GNU Octave Command Window showing unreadable text.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. GNU Octave 4.2.2. Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2). Octave was installed by means of the Terminal.

[image: Command Window]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? what version of octave and how did you install it? what graphics hardware do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. GNU Octave 4.2.2. Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2). Octave was installed by means of the Terminal.

Comment: The Ubuntu 16.04 repository has Octave version 4.0.0. Using a newer version of Octave with this version of Ubuntu may result in some incompatibilities.

Answer (score 11):

A workaround for this problem is to switch from the Courier font to some other font in the preferences settings under Edit - Preferences - Terminal - Font.  I went with the DejaVu Sans Mono font and the problem went away.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS upgraded to 17.10 version. GNU Octave Command Window and Editor are working just fine.